# On change event on d3.js library duplicate charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm trying to do a chart with the help of the d3.js library,my data come from two sources and have the same format(tsv),I use a form to try to change the chart displayed according to which button has been clicked.My problem actually is that when I change the chart choice, the labels are duplicated as well as my charts.

My form look like this:

```
<form>
  <label><input name="radio" type="radio"  value="Incoming"/> Incoming</label>
  <label><input name="radio" type="radio"  value="Outgoing" checked="checked"/> Outgoing</label>
</form>
```

And the javascript part to retrieve values of the checked radio input:

```
draw("data.tsv");//on load load the default checked
d3.selectAll("input").on("change", change);

function change(){

  var radios = document.getElementsByName('radio');

  for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
      if(radios[i].value=="Outgoing"){
        draw("data.tsv");
        console.log(radios[i].value);

      }
      else{
        draw("datasecond.tsv");
         console.log(radios[i].value);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you to give some advices!!!

**EDIT:**
the draw function:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

function draw(data){
  d3.tsv(data, function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

  //data.forEach(function(d) {
  //  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  //});
  var cities="";
  cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, temperature: +d[name]};
      })
    };
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(cities, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); }),
    d3.max(cities, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); })
  ]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Number");

  var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

  city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  city.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")"; })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });


});

}
```

Comment: What does the draw() function do?

Comment: the function draw the chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is hard to say without seeing the code of your draw function, but I guess that the explanation is that you are creating new axis() objects each time you call draw, instead of reusing the existing ones. 
be sure that you keep references to your axis objects. create them once, and in your draw function reuse those instances.

Comment: let me add the function

Comment: yeap, you are using  svg.append("g")...call(yAxis) each time you call draw. it means that in each call, a new set of labels are added to your graph. instead of append, either select the existing element or store a reference to the first one to avoid this problem.

Comment: I used remove()function to remove the previous chart,now I still have problem to remove labels(update the labels and get the new)

Comment: You will need to do the same thing.  ie. call .remove() on the label objects and then re-add them, just as you are apparently doing to the chart objects.